# facebook like-button for blog's header & facebook share-buttons for each post

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, blogger, addthis

I've got the blog (http://loveclubhouse.blogspot.com/).

**(1)**
I added one like-button on top of my blog. This is global like-button for the whole blog. It's available from every page of my blog, so that users may express their attitude to the blog in general (doesn't matter which post of the blog they read at the moment).

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Floveclubhouse.blogspot.com%2F&amp;action=like&amp;...></iframe>
```

I use facebook's Open Graph. So, when the user clicks on this like-button the story is created on his facebook's wall with the title, description, and preview-image that was previously defined in the Open Graph's Meta tags of my blog.

```
<meta content='DJ Club Mixes 2012' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
<meta content='http://loveclubhouse.blogspot.com/' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='Blog's cover image URL' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='Blog's description' property='og:description'/>
```

**(2)**
In addition to the global like-button I have also added standard "addthis" share-buttons for every post of my blog (let's say the user wants to share on his wall a certain post from my blog).

```
<div class='addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style' expr:addthis:title='data:post.title' expr:addthis:url='data:post.url'>
   <a class='addthis_button_facebook'/>
   ...
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var addthis_config = {ui_click:true, data_track_clickback:true};
</script>
<script src='http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4d68d12853670207' type='text/javascript'/>
```

However, when the user clicks on share-button for post,  the facebook generates the story on his wall with the same preview-image and title that was set up for the whole blog.

The question is:

How to combine **(1)** and **(2)**, so that the user may like my blog in general and the user may share specific posts on his wall with the title and preview-image for this particular post?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the OG tags on your page.  When a user visits a different page in your blog, you need to be sure that the og:title and og:description (and og:image if you want) are updated to reflect the current article of your blog.